# How insert Link nofollow on webflow in posts

Tags: hyperlink, nofollow, webflow

I am writing on webflow (webflow dot com) but I do not know how to insert nofollow link on webflow. Does anyone know if it can show me?

Comment: https://forum.webflow.com/t/how-to-add-nofollow-tags-on-links/44880

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, add it in Custom Attributes:

[image: like this]